# Nome das Colunas em maiúsculas com Codeigniter e PostgreeSQL

Tags: php, codeigniter, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema WEB usando o Codeigniter com suporte para banco Oracle e PostgreSQL.

Nas minhas consultas, utilizo o Query Builder do próprio Codeigniter.

Exemplo de Select simples:

`SELECT "ID", "NOME" FROM "USUARIO"`

Entanto, esse select funciona normalmente no Oracle.
Já no PostgreSQL, ele me retorna um erro onde não existem essas colunas.

Para funcionar normalmente configurei o _protect_identifiers e funcionou, então o select ficou assim: `SELECT ID, NOME FROM USUARIO`

O problema agora é quando ele retorna no array, no oracle ele retorna o array com as keys maiúsculas e o pgsql retorna minúsculo. Não consigo chegar no meio termo. O que eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Qual seria o "meio termo"?

Comment: Eu faço um select para Oracle e PostGree no Codeigniter.
Na hora de varrer o select, ele me retorna as chaves do array diferentes, no oracle ele me retorna maiúsculo e no postgree minúsculo. Não consigo achar uma forma de acessar os valores do array independete das chaves que vier. Queria saber se tem alguma forma de eu fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, se você usa ***mesmo*** o query builder do CodeIgniter, essa questão deveria ser irrelevante. Veja o seu exemplo dado sendo construído pelo query builder:

```
$this->db->select('id, nome');
$query = $this->db->get('usuario');
```

E as colunas poderão ser acessadas assim:

```
$meu_id = $query->row()->id;
$meu_nome = $query->row()->nome;
```

O PHP é case insensitive, isto é, qualquer variância no *case* das variáveis do resultset não impede a vizualização das mesmas:

```
$meu_id = $query->row()->ID; // Isto funciona igual
$meu_nome = $query->row()->NOME; // Perfeito também
```

Agora se o problema está no método `select( )` do query builder, por não achar as colunas, o que não deveria acontecer, simplesmente escreva tudo em maiúsculas. O Oracle deve ser capaz de achar colunas em minúsculas escritas em maíusculas.

```
$this->db->select('ID, NOME'); // Isto deve ser entendido pelos bancos
```

Ou ainda, você teria que padronizar, em todos os bancos utilizados, ou para maiúsculas ou para minúsculas. Mas esta é uma solução de pior qualidade. Antes verifique se você está com a última versão do CodeIgniter, porque este pode ser um problema já resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não necessariamente estou com erro na query builder, estou com esse problema quando o banco retorna o array com os valores, no postgree, ele me retorna as keys minusculas e no oracle, ele me retorna maiusculas e estou usando a versão mais recente do CI.

Comment: Olá @Huhifeku, o que vem a ser as `keys` que você menciona? São instâncias de qual classe ou qual seu tipo? Quando você tenta acessá-las, que erro obtém? Pode demonstrar uma linha onde você as emprega?

Comment: Dentro de um model, ao final de um método, eu chamo return  `$query->result_array(); ` para me retornar o array com os valores da minha consulta, correto? Ele me retorna um array, no postgree, o array vem assim:

 `$array = ('nome' => 'João'); `

e no Oracle:

 `$array = ('NOME' => 'João'); `

Percebeu que as keys estão diferentes? Então, esse é o problema, queria automatizar esse processo pra vir de um jeito só, onde independente de quando eu for varrer o array, é pra eu conseguir acessar esses valores.

Comment: @Huhifeku, Entendi. É porque no PHP índices de vetores são sim _case sensitive_. A função `array_change_key_case( )` resolve seu problema. Ao invés de utilizar diretamente `$query->result_array();` utilize `array_change_key_case($query->result_array());`. Os índices sempre ficaram em minúsculas, a menos que você os queira em maiúsculas: `array_change_key_case($query->result_array(), CASE_UPPER);`.